# Updating dataframe based on user input

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
v    w    e   
dog  cat  -> 
frog cat  -> 
frog dog  -> 
frog fish ->
fish cat  ->
```

This is the function I wrote. It will output an updated  dataframe based on the user input. The inputs V, W, and E can be a single string or a list. But V, W, and E must have the same length.

```
convert_df <- function(df, V, W, E) {
  df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(flag = (v %in% V & w %in% W | w %in% V & v %in% W),
                  txt = ifelse(flag, paste(V,E,W), paste(v,e,w)))
}
```

For example, this would be my expected output for the following. As you can see I want to change  the txt column dog <-> frog and cat <-> dog :

```
> V <- c('dog', 'cat')
> W <- c('frog', 'dog')
> E <- c('<->', '<->')
> convert_df(df,V,W,E)

v    w    e   
dog  cat  <-> 
frog cat  -> 
frog dog  <-> 
frog fish ->
fish cat  ->
```

However my function will output

```
dog  cat  <-> 
frog cat  <-> 
frog dog  <-> 
frog fish ->
fish cat  ->
```

How can i fix my function? The indexes for V,W, and E are aligned to what i want to change in the dataframe. And my current function just checks if the v and w are in V and W regardless of the index alignment.

**UPDATE:**

Here I switch the order of V and W for the first element. I want to make my function dynamic so that the following would give the expected result as well:

```
> V <- c('frog', 'cat')
> W <- c('dog', 'dog')
> E <- c('<->', '<->')
> convert_df(df,V,W,E)

v    w    e   
dog  cat  <-> 
frog cat  -> 
frog dog  <-> 
frog fish ->
fish cat  ->
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this with a join:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~v,   ~w,   ~e,   
"dog","cat", "->",
"frog","cat", "->", 
"frog","dog", "->",
"frog","fish","->",
"fish","cat", "->") 


v <- c('dog', 'frog')
w <- c('cat', 'dog')
E <- c('<->', '<->')

newdat <- do.call(data.frame, list(v=v,w=w,E=E))

df <- left_join(df, newdat) %>% 
  mutate(e = ifelse(is.na(E), e, E)) %>% 
  select(-E)


# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#    v     w     e    
# <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 dog   cat   <->  
# 2 frog  cat   ->   
# 3 frog  dog   <->  
# 4 frog  fish  ->   
# 5 fish  cat   ->
```

Comment: Is there a reason do `do.call(data.frame, list(v=v,w=w,E=E))` when you can do just `data.frame(v=v,w=w,E=E)`?

Comment: Also, you can replace your `ifelse` with `coalesce(E, e)`, a handy `NA`-handling function in `dplyr`.

Comment: I just updated my question - I also want the function to work if the inputs of v and w are swapped by the user.

Comment: @Eisen Just do a double `left_join`: `df %>% left_join(df2, by = c("v" = "V", "w" = "W")) %>% left_join(df2, by = c("v" = "W", "w" = "V")) %>% mutate(E = coalesce(E.y, E.x, e))`.